# What does $P(x, r)$ parallelepiped mean?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The book says, in the theorem about local measure distortion,

let
$v: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ be continuously differentable, $U$ be open, and $\forall x \in U \ \det Dv(x) \neq 0$, where $Dv(x)$ is Jacobian of $v$ at $x\in U$. $P$ is a parallelepiped with center at $(0, \ldots, 0).$

Then, $$\lim_{r\to0}\frac{\mu_L((v (P(x, r)))}{\mu_L(P(x, r))} = \left|\det Dv(x)\right|.$$

I am confused what could $P(x, r)$ mean. Earlier, a parallelepiped is defined as $P=\langle a_1, b_1\rangle \times \ldots \times \langle a_k, b_k \rangle$, and $\mu_L(P)= \Pi_{i=1}^k(b_i-a_i),$ but definition of $P(x, r)$ isn't given.

Comment: Consider the cartexian plane XY; in it two intervals $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2)$ identify a "rectangular" region.

Comment: Then consider the case "centered" on $(0,0)$ is such that $x_1 < 0 < x_2$ and $y_1 < 0 < y_2$.

Comment: In set language, the above "rectangular" region is $(x_1,x_2) \times (y_1,y_2)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I understand, but it doesn't give a hint about who $r \in \mathbb{R}$ is.

Comment: Something like considering an interval $(a, b)$ centered on $0$ and "shrinking" it with $\lim_{b \to 0}$

Comment: My view is that $P(x,r)$ is a parallelipiped centred at $x$ with side lengths $r$. Then what you are doing is finding the area of the parallelipiped transformed by $v$ divided by the area of the standard parallelipiped.